# How to deserialize JSON in portable library

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

Do you know any JSON frameworks suitable for portable class libraries (Win RT, WP8, Silverlight 5)?

Comment: Thx, they've released a new version recently that support portable library. Please, write it as an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) which supports all of your platforms

Answer (score 0):

You can create project of special type Portable Class Library, that will contains code for serialization and deserialization of your models